# pass React Context value as function parameter

Tags: reactjs

When calling a function (from another file), I'm unable to pass a context value as function parameter.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useContext } from React
import { AuthContext } from "src/contexts/AuthContext";

import { MyFunc } from "src/function/MyFunc";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleClick = () => {
      const userIdVal = user.uid;

      console.log("userIdVal: ",userIdVal);
      MyFunc(userIdVal);
  };

  return (
  <>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Run Function</button>
  </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Code for MyFunc.js

```
export const MyFunc = ({ userId }) => {
  console.log("userId: ", userId)
  return true;
};
```

A sample console output is:

```
userIdVal: 1234567890
userId: undefined
```

Is there a way to pass the value rather than the reference into a function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here has nothing to do with context, it has to do with the function signature.

In MyFun, the parameter an object with a property of userId.
This clearly won't work, and so the solution is simply to change the function to the following:

```
export const MyFunc = ( userId ) => {
  console.log("userId: ", userId)
  return true;
};
```

Or, pass an object with userId as a property, something like this:

```
MyFunc({ userId: user.id })
```

It's a silly mistake, that was very nicely pointed out to me in the [Reactiflux discord](https://www.reactiflux.com/) by the very helpful user *click2install™*.

I opted to change the function.